# Get all href URLs inside div class using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all URLs that are sitting inside the div class using beautifulsoup. Below is my HTML structure that I am trying to parse -

```
    <div class="someclass">
    <div style="width:375px; float:left;">
    <a href="link1"</div>

    <div style="width:375px; float:left;">
    <a href="link2"</div>

    <div style="width:375px; float:left;">
    <a href="link3"</div>   

</div>
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong here but I am unable to get all 3 URLs.

```
for li in soup.find_all('div',class_='someclass'):
            for link in li.find_all('style'):
                    some_link=link.find('a')['href']
                    print (some_link)
```

Comment: Assuming class name is ```someclass```, you wanted ```class_='someclass'``` not this ```class_='some-class'```

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari sorry i have edited my question. I am referring to the correct class name but still not getting the URL's.

Comment: beautifulsoup 4.7+ [supports CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), so why not select all `<a>` directly using the same CSS selectors you would use on an actual web page? `find_all('div[class=someclass] a')`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans awesome your suggestion worked. Appreciated !